# How to list all video ID's from users without playlist in youtube V3 api

Tags: php, video, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have uploaded like 100 videos to my channel,I need to get all the video ID , But everywhere i search there is code for only listing videos inside playlist.but all my videos are in root.

```
$channelsResponse = $youTubeService->channels->listChannels('id,contentDetails', array(
    'mine' => 'true'));
$searchResponse = $youTubeService->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', array(
        'maxResults' => 50,
        'fields' => 'items(snippet(publishedAt,channelId,title,description,thumbnails(default),resourceId)),pageInfo,nextPageToken'));
echo json_encode($searchResponse['items']['contentDetails']['videoId']);
```

Above code gets videos from playlist.how can i get videos from root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like root, everything is in playlists in YouTube. I believe what you are asking is to get your uploaded videos. There is also a playlist called "uploads" in your channel. That's where your channels uploaded videos added.

You can get the playlistID of that playlist in your listChannels call. In the response, look for [contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads).

Then in your second call (listPlaylistItems), use that id to set [playlistId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#playlistId)

[Here's the PHP sample.](https://github.com/youtube/yt-samples-php/blob/master/my_uploads.php)

Comment: I am using jquery api, but I think I am getting playlist wrong, I have 1 youtube channel in which I have 2 playlists p1 and p2 in each playlist there 10 videos, I want to get p1 and p2 title and id to get p1 OR p2 videos only in 3rd request

Answer (score 0):

working solution/exmample:

```
function getSslPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

//params
$order = "date";
$part = "snippet";
$channel_id = "UCzocxfp9lrNal14glrFSrng";
$max_results = 50;
$api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY";

$feedurl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order='.$order.'&part='.$part.'&channelId='.$channel_id.'&maxResults='.$max_results.'&key='.$api_key;

$feed = getSslPage($feedurl);
$feed_arr = json_decode($feed, true);

//print_r($feed_arr);

$items = $feed_arr['items'];

foreach($items as $item) {
   if( (isset($item['id']['videoId'])) OR (!empty($item['id']['videoId'])) ) {
        echo '<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$item['id']['videoId'].'?autoplay=0">
</iframe>';
   }
}
```